# Slim Error while defining middleware

Tags: php, slim-3

I'm using `Slim v3` and `PHP-DI` for dependency injection. I extended `Slim\App` to define a function `route` to handle all HTTP methods and middleware for the route. The definition for the function:

```
    public function route($method, $pattern, $callableMiddleware, $callable)
    {
        switch($method) {
            case "GET":
                if(empty($callableMiddleware)) {
                    return $this->map(['GET'], $pattern, $callable);
                }
                return $this->map(['GET'], $pattern, $callable)->add($callableMiddleware);
                break;
            ...
            ...
            default:
                throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP Method");
                break;
        }
    }
```

While I tried to call the function:

```
$app->route("GET", "/{id}", \App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware::class . '::check', \App\Controllers\Controller::class . "::get");
```

I got following issue:

```
Type: Invoker\Exception\NotCallableException
Message: Cannot call check on App\Middleware\AuthMiddleware because it is not a class nor a valid container entry
File: /var/www/html/event/vendor/php-di/invoker/src/CallableResolver.php
Line: 98
```

**AuthMiddleware.php**

```
namespace App\Middleware;


use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class AuthMiddleware
{
    public function check(Request $request, Response $response) {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me where have I done wrong? What would be the solution for this issue?

Comment: as i see it from the docs https://www.slimframework.com/docs/concepts/middleware.html your way of doing/adding the middleware is wrong

Comment: I just wanted to use the class=>method instead of a function as in `$mw = function ($request, $response, $next) {
    ....
    return $response;
};

$app->get('/', function ($request, $response, $args) {
 $response->getBody()->write(' Hello ');

 return $response;
})->add($mw);`. So how can I do that?

Comment: you are trying to use the middleware as a Controller, consult the docks